# Are there large-scale, practical situations where the following multiple testing scenario applies?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Consider test sites $X_1, X_2.... X_m$ arranged in some linear order (like say they are physically arranged in a line). For each test site, we want to test $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ for some parameter $\mu$ and constant $\mu_0$. We know that if a test site is a true positive (we should reject $H_0$), then there is a greater chance that other test sites adjacent to it are also true positives. My question is, are there large-scale scenarios where this setting can apply?

For example, in the small scale, it can apply to soil testing. You can imagine dividing a long piece of land into sections and the hypothesis test measures if a section of soil has some desirable characteristic, such as if its soil pH is above 5.6 (suitable for most crops). We know that if a section of soil has this, then it is likely that sections next to it also have it. I want to ask if there was a situation involving thousands of "sections" that this can fit into.

Comment: What would be the hypothesis you want to test?  It's not very practical or meaningful to test the arbitrarily large number of hypotheses you describe.  Could you frame your question in the language of soil science instead?

Comment: I added more context in the example. Say we want to test if soil pH for each section is higher than some threshold (to see which sections are suitable for farming a specific crop for example). Note though that I am looking for an application not necessarily in soil science.

Comment: This is an example of correlated priors. I have seen some work on multiple Bayesian testing in this situation, I think in the journal Biometrics.

Answer (score 0):

One clear example is genomics, either with SNP chip data or sequencing data.  In this context each chromosome has a linear sequence of genetic variants. Association between a variant and a phenotype at one position means there is more likely to be association at neighbouring positions, both because of correlation between the variants ("linkage disequilibrium") and because functional variants will tend to occur in or near genes that are relevant for the phenotype.

It's not a *single* line, because the ordering of chromosomes (by size) is purely conventional, but it's a small set of lines and there are hundreds of thousands of variants on some chromosomes (a mixture of directly measured and imputed variants)

Comment: May I have a bit more clarification? You said that the ordering is purely conventional and by size but in the previous paragraph you mention position of variants. Is the sequence of  genetic variants for a single chromosome arranged in a single line?

Comment: If you use the HapMap Phase 2 panel, for example there are 2.2 million variants across 23 chromosomes. The ordering of the 23 chromosomes is arbitrary, but the ordering of variants within chromosomes is real physical proximity

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much. I tried looking up data from the HapMap Phase 2 panel but I am not sure if it is openly accessible. Would you know of a resource where I might be able to access an example of this data?